# Cookies fail after second time through

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

So I have a bit of a problem.

On my site, users log in on the main page, and they can log out once they are inside the site.

Right now, users CAN log in, and then log back out. When they log in, cookies are set, and when they log out, the cookies are deleted.

However, if they log in (cookies are set), log out (cookies deleted), log in a second time (cookies are again set), and attempt to log out again, the cookies are NOT deleted.

Any idea why that might be happening?

Below is the code I use to set the cookies and deleted the cookies:

SET COOKIES:

```
<?php

...code to get the variables used below (database query)

setcookie("Email", $user_info['Email'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("First_Name", $user_info['First_Name'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Last_Name", $user_info['Last_Name'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Full_Name", $user_info['First_Name']." ".$user_info['Last_Name'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("User_Type", $user_info['User_Type'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Do_Not_Show_Modals", $user_info['Do_Not_Show_Modals'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Org_ID", $user_info['Company_ID'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Org_Name", $user_info['Org_Name'], time()+1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

header("Location: Inside_the_site");
?>
```

DELETE COOKIES

```
<?php

unset($_COOKIE['Email']);
unset($_COOKIE['First_Name']);
unset($_COOKIE['Last_Name']);
unset($_COOKIE['Full_Name']);
unset($_COOKIE['User_Type']);
unset($_COOKIE['Do_Not_Show_Modals']);
unset($_COOKIE['Org_ID']);
unset($_COOKIE['Org_Name']);
unset($_COOKIE['_ga']);

setcookie("Email", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("First_Name", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Last_Name", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Full_Name", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("User_Type", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Do_Not_Show_Modals", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Org_ID", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
setcookie("Org_Name", "DELETE", time()-1209600, '/', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

header("Location: https://www.homepage.com");
?>
```

Comment: What is $_COOKIE['_ga']?

Comment: Everything seems to be fine - deleting a cookie is a trivial task. Did you try to debug - to see the messages, sent from and to the server?

Comment: Sorry, $_COOKIE['_ga'] shouldn't be in there.

Comment: Nothing comes up in Firebug. When I use firebug to check the cookies, thats how I can tell that it correctly sets them and deletes them the first time through, then correctly sets, then does NOT delete

Comment: Use sessions.. Don't put too much in cookies. Use serialize or json_encode

Comment: @TonTon4Life In firebug there is a Net panel. Check out the server response. Pay attention to cookies being sent by the server. Is the expiry date in the past when you try to logout for the second time?

Comment: The expiry date is the same as when the cookies are set. So I guess the question is why does that happen the second time but works fine the first time?